# How to ignore img class from a single image

Tags: jquery, css, image, responsive-design, zooming

I am using CSS to make sure that images are not bigger than there parent to ensure responsiveness and that everything looks good.

but I just added a image zoom. but its showing the hole image inside the zoom area instead of just a bugger image

i know if if remove the max-width:100% in the img tag it works well but the rest of the site does not

my css

```
img {
  /* Responsive images (ensure images don't scale beyond their parents) */

   max-width: 100%;
  /* Part 1: Set a maxium relative to the parent */

  width: auto\9;
  /* IE7-8 need help adjusting responsive images */

  height: auto;
  /* Part 2: Scale the height according to the width, otherwise you get stretching */

  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 0;
  -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
}
```

i just want to ignore this when i called it from a particular image or JavaScript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should simply be able to do this to override it:

```
#IDofSomeImage{
    max-width: none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ahxpg/

This works due to [css specificity](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) rules.  As long as this rule is more specific than the other, it will take precedence.